# How would I send a command if a .bat file is closed?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file

I want my .bat file to send a command to another .bat file or run a .bat file if the originial is closed?

Would this be possible?

Would it be possible for me to prevent closure of the .bat file?

Working on the most recent windows.

Comment: What is your batch files objective to force it running. I can think of some harmful things I won't support.

Comment: If BatFile1.bat is opening BatFile2.bat you can send arguments along with the START command. If instead you're trying to pass variables along between to simultaneously running BAT files, you could write them to system variables, or to a file they'll both access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file is a simple script. If its not running, it cannot do anything, and you cannot prevent a script from being closed.

I think you're looking for a way to fire a batch file at specific events. The windows Task Scheduler is likely going to help you with this, but given that you have not included much info about what you actually want to accomplish, I cannot write you the perfect answer.

Long story short, what you want (given the little information in the question) cannot be done. Batch script is a simple language that basically executes commands in a row as if they were typed in the command window. For more advanced scripting, scripts like powershell and VBScript were made. They can likely do what you want, but again, I have no idea what your ultimate goal is.